# structuring media uploads (users, images, videos) using sequelize.js

Tags: postgresql, database-design

(using pseudocode to simplify)

say I have a User (`users` table)

```
User {
  id: PK
}
```

and I want to have them upload images and videos (media). I want to be able to differentiate between images or videos but they have overlapping fields beyond their media types. so that I can query for all of their media, or just videos or images.

I am unsure of the best way to structure this. here are two options I came up with

Option 1: use `media` table with a `media_type` column (enum values `video` and `image`)

```
Media {
  id: PK
  media_type: enum (image, video)
  uploader_id: FK (users.id)
  url: VC
  length: Int (null for images)
}
```

sequelize:

- `user.getMedia();` // get all media
- `user.getMedia({ where: { media_type: 'image' } });` // get images
- `user.getMedia({ where: { media_type: 'video' } });` // get videos

I could also use the `scope` (on `media_type`) and `alias` (`Images`, `Videos`) options on the Model.associate to create `getMedia()`, `getImages()`, `getVideos()` methods.

---

Option 2: separate `images` and `videos` tables

```
Image {
  id: PK
  uploader_id: FK (users.id)
  url: VC
}


Video {
  id: PK
  uploader_id: FK (users.id)
  url: VC
  length: Int
}
```

sequelize:

- `user.getVideos();`
- `user.getImages();`

So my questions are:

- which option (of the above 2 or another you have) is preferred and why?
- if option 1 is chosen does it become unmanageable if I add more media types?
- how do I do `getAllMedia()` for the second option? The only thing I can think of is to write a custom prototype method that queries each table and reduces them (in order of upload date). this seems incorrect.
- say I also keep track of all the User's likes from the media they view. option 1 would allow me to keep the `media.id` FK on the `likes` table. option 2 appears to lead me to `image_likes` and `video_likes` which seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I am leaning towards Option 1 for this because I actually think that as you add more media types option 2 is going to get unmanageable when it comes to querying, especially when you are trying to get all of a user's media, it would just require too much eager loading of the other tables, or a lot of join tables.

With option one, each piece of media has it's own unique id, so if you set up the association between Users, Media, and Likes so that:
Likes belongTo users 
Users can hasMany Likes 
Media can hasMany Likes 
Likes hasOne media (so each individual like is a representation of it's userId and the mediaId it was associated to)

then you would be able to query your Likes table for all Likes with a certain userId (to show all the media a user has liked), or for all Likes for a certain mediaId (ex. to show the amount of likes for a specific image).

You wouldn't even necessarily have to specify the media type when querying likes because you'd have your mediaId or UserId depending on what you are trying to query.